# How to disable the "Save As..." option in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to ask, how can I disable or hide the "Save As..." setting from QGIS3? I want user to only use the Save To.. setting, where they can save the project into postgreSQL or GeoPackage, I don't want them to save the project in their local folder. Is there anyway to do it?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what you need to do to the codebase to remove that or are you asking for a method to do that through the GUI?

Comment: @Dodge, method to do it through GUI, are you able to provide some info on method to do it through GUI?